# Поменять местами элементы словаря

Tags: python, словари, dict

Вопрос может быть не серьезный, но никак не соображу и в сети ничего толкового не найти.
Есть список словарей:

```
[
{'Цитата': 'Каждый миг наслаждения — это дар богов. ', 'Автор': 'Клод Адриан Гельвеций', 'Ссылка': 'http://forismatic.com/ru/20376e8629/'}, 
{'Цитата': 'Вместо того, чтобы посвятить себя миру, человек растрачивает себя на дела. ', 'Автор': 'Карлос Кастанеда', 'Ссылка': 'http://forismatic.com/ru/9208878436/'}, 
{'Цитата': 'Ничего не принимайте близко к сердцу. Немногое на свете долго бывает важным.', 'Автор': 'Эрих Мария Ремарк', 'Ссылка': 'http://forismatic.com/ru/ee22b4e505/'}
]
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как преобразовать словари, чтобы сначала шел автор, затем цитата, затем ссылка.

Comment: вам это для вывода? поскольку для работы какая разница в каком порядке ключи в словаре

Comment: Потом просто необходимо записать файл csv именно в такой последовательности

Comment: ну тогда при записи в файл (как и при выводе на экран) и указывайте в такой последовательности, не трогая сам словарь

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вообще спрашивается зачем?

Для вывода на экран можно решить в лоб, а для доступа к элементам порядок не важен

Но если очень чешется, то можно сделать так:

```
data = [
    {'Цитата': 'Каждый миг наслаждения — это дар богов. ', 'Автор': 'Клод Адриан Гельвеций', 'Ссылка': 'http://forismatic.com/ru/20376e8629/'},
    {'Цитата': 'Вместо того, чтобы посвятить себя миру, человек растрачивает себя на дела. ', 'Автор': 'Карлос Кастанеда', 'Ссылка': 'http://forismatic.com/ru/9208878436/'},
    {'Цитата': 'Ничего не принимайте близко к сердцу. Немногое на свете долго бывает важным.', 'Автор': 'Эрих Мария Ремарк', 'Ссылка': 'http://forismatic.com/ru/ee22b4e505/'}
]

data = [{'Автор': obj['Автор'], 'Цитата': obj['Цитата'], 'Ссылка': obj['Ссылка']} for obj in data]

print(*data, sep='\n')
```

будет выведено:

```
{'Автор': 'Клод Адриан Гельвеций', 'Цитата': 'Каждый миг наслаждения — это дар богов. ', 'Ссылка': 'http://forismatic.com/ru/20376e8629/'}
{'Автор': 'Карлос Кастанеда', 'Цитата': 'Вместо того, чтобы посвятить себя миру, человек растрачивает себя на дела. ', 'Ссылка': 'http://forismatic.com/ru/9208878436/'}
{'Автор': 'Эрих Мария Ремарк', 'Цитата': 'Ничего не принимайте близко к сердцу. Немногое на свете долго бывает важным.', 'Ссылка': 'http://forismatic.com/ru/ee22b4e505/'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Лучше не полагаться на внутреннее устройство словаря, а просто выводить поля в нужной последовательности:

```
dict_list =[
{'Цитата': 'Каждый миг наслаждения — это дар богов. ', 'Автор': 'Клод Адриан Гельвеций', 'Ссылка': 'http://forismatic.com/ru/20376e8629/'}, 
{'Цитата': 'Вместо того, чтобы посвятить себя миру, человек растрачивает себя на дела. ', 'Автор': 'Карлос Кастанеда', 'Ссылка': 'http://forismatic.com/ru/9208878436/'}, 
{'Цитата': 'Ничего не принимайте близко к сердцу. Немногое на свете долго бывает важным.', 'Автор': 'Эрих Мария Ремарк', 'Ссылка': 'http://forismatic.com/ru/ee22b4e505/'}
]

for d in dict_list:
    for k in ['Автор', 'Цитата', 'Ссылка']:
        print(f'{k}: {d[k]}')
    print()
```

Результат:

```
Автор: Клод Адриан Гельвеций
Цитата: Каждый миг наслаждения — это дар богов. 
Ссылка: http://forismatic.com/ru/20376e8629/

Автор: Карлос Кастанеда
Цитата: Вместо того, чтобы посвятить себя миру, человек растрачивает себя на дела. 
Ссылка: http://forismatic.com/ru/9208878436/

Автор: Эрих Мария Ремарк
Цитата: Ничего не принимайте близко к сердцу. Немногое на свете долго бывает важным.
Ссылка: http://forismatic.com/ru/ee22b4e505/
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете заполнять словарь изначально в необходимой последовательности.
Также, не думаю что вам правда нужна определенная последовательность, т.к вы можете получать значения из словаря независимо от последовательностей.

Answer (score 0):

Если хочется хранить отсортированный словарь, то используйте `OrderedDict` из `collections`. Вот как пример сортировка по алфавиту

```
from collections import OrderedDict

dict_list = [
{'Цитата': 'Каждый миг наслаждения — это дар богов. ', 'Автор': 'Клод Адриан Гельвеций', 'Ссылка': 'http://forismatic.com/ru/20376e8629/'},
{'Цитата': 'Вместо того, чтобы посвятить себя миру, человек растрачивает себя на дела. ', 'Автор': 'Карлос Кастанеда', 'Ссылка': 'http://forismatic.com/ru/9208878436/'},
{'Цитата': 'Ничего не принимайте близко к сердцу. Немногое на свете долго бывает важным.', 'Автор': 'Эрих Мария Ремарк', 'Ссылка': 'http://forismatic.com/ru/ee22b4e505/'}
]

for i in range(len(dict_list)):
    dict_list[i] = OrderedDict(sorted(dict_list[i].items(), key=lambda a: a[0]))

for i in dict_list:
    print(i, end="\n")
```

Вывод:

```
OrderedDict([('Автор', 'Клод Адриан Гельвеций'), ('Ссылка', 'http://forismatic.com/ru/20376e8629/'), ('Цитата', 'Каждый миг наслаждения — это дар богов. ')])
OrderedDict([('Автор', 'Карлос Кастанеда'), ('Ссылка', 'http://forismatic.com/ru/9208878436/'), ('Цитата', 'Вместо того, чтобы посвятить себя миру, человек растрачивает себя на дела. ')])
OrderedDict([('Автор', 'Эрих Мария Ремарк'), ('Ссылка', 'http://forismatic.com/ru/ee22b4e505/'), ('Цитата', 'Ничего не принимайте близко к сердцу. Немногое на свете долго бывает важным.')])
```